# "subscript out of range" error when trying to set secondary start page

Tags: arrays, vbscript

Can you please read this code and let me where I am wrong?

For a quick overview, I am reading an HKCU MultiStringValue for secondary start pages for IE homepages and enforcing my own as first item in the list while keeping the user's presets as rest of the values.

When I have my url and user's preset all combined coming back, script runs fine but if I ONLY have mine set, the `allURLs` throws an error

> Subscript out of range

even though I am placing my enforced URL into `allURLs(0)` so it's not empty and initialized correctly on the top.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ObjName, oADSysInfo, strComputer
Dim objReg, IE_Main, mstrValName, strFunctionIntranet, strNYHomepage, _
    multiStringValues(), allURLs(), itemname, a, return
Set oADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set ObjName = GetObject("LDAP://" & oADSysInfo.UserName)
strComputer = "."
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
Const HKCU = &H80000001
IE_Main = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"
mstrValName = "Secondary Start Pages"

strNYHomepage = "http://www.google.com"
strFunctionIntranet = "www.mycompany.com"

SetHomePage

Sub SetHomepage
    objReg.setStringValue HKCU, IE_Main, "Start Page", strNYHomepage

    'Reading MultiStringValue of "Secondary Start Pages" for HKCU
    'and continuing if it has something preset.
    return = objReg.getMultiStringValue(HKCU, IE_Main, mstrValName, multiStringValues)

    If return = 0 Then
        a = 0
        'Reading all items currently set to make sure users retain
        'their existing URLs.
        For Each itemname In multiStringValues
            'Only continue if any of the existing URLs DO NOT MATCH
            'what we are enforcing as the URL.
            If itemname <> strFunctionIntranet Then
                WScript.Echo itemname
                WScript.Echo "itemname is NOT equal intranet"
                a = a + 1
                ReDim Preserve allURLs(a)
                allURLs(a) = itemname
                'a = a + 1
            End If
        Next

        objReg.DeleteValue HKCU,IE_Main,mstrValName
        'Enforce our URL to always be the first item.
        allURLs(0) = strFunctionIntranet    '<<< This is the ERROR

        'Set the new MultiStringValue registry key back.
        objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU, IE_Main, mstrValName, allURLs
        WScript.echo "finished setting all secondary tabs... "
    Else
      strFunctionIntranet = Array(strFunctionIntranet)
      objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU, IE_Main, mstrValName, strFunctionIntranet
    End If
End Sub
Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that the `GetMultiStringValues` call is successful, but returns an empty result. Because of that the `For Each` loop is skipped and you go straight to the statement

```
allURLs(0) = strFunctionIntranet
```

However, `allURLs` was defined like this:

```
Dim allURLs()
```

which creates a variable of type `Variant()`, but without an actual size, so you can't use it unless you `ReDim` it first. [*Never* declare arrays that way](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/dyn_vbs_arrays.shtml). *Always* define arrays with a proper size, in your case for instance like this:

```
ReDim allURLs(0)
```

That defines an array of size 1 (i.e. an array that can hold one element), since you want at least one URL in that list.

If you need to add further elements to the array, resize it like this:

```
ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)
```

so you can add the next element in the new last slot like this:

```
allURLs(UBound(allURLs)) = newvalue
```

That way you also don't need a separate counter for keeping track of the array size.

Also, if you want to pre-fill an array anyway, do it first thing, not after you put everything else in it.

```
ReDim allURLs(0)
...
Sub SetHomepage
    objReg.setStringValue HKCU, IE_Main, "Start Page", strNYHomepage
    return = objReg.getMultiStringValue(...)

    If return = 0 Then
        allURLs(0) = strFunctionIntranet
        For Each itemname In multiStringValues
            If itemname <> strFunctionIntranet Then
                'grow array by 1 and append itemname
                ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)
                allURLs(UBound(allURLs)) = itemname
            End If
        Next

        objReg.DeleteValue HKCU, IE_Main, mstrValName
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, I will modify and will post back my result.

Comment: Alright so I made the changes that improved the logic all together.I changed the Dim allURLs() to Dim allURLS(0) on top and made changes you have posted above with UBound.Now the error changed to "This array is fixed or temporarily locked" at line "ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)". Currently I have my own,msn and google coming back from getvalue line. Thanks.

Comment: It's `ReDim allURLs(0)`, not `Dim allURLs(0)`. The latter would create an array of fixed size.

Comment: You are just amazing. I have tried varIous iterations of conditions and all now work fine. Even the conditions where it could break with empty strings yet no failure. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! Appreciate your help greatly and sorry for the original post issue.